# How to get the group of a windows account/user on a computer(not part of a domain)

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-6.0

I am trying to get the Groups a Windows user is part of in C#,.net 6. I am on a Windows 11 Home edition, there is only one user on the computer which is part of Administrators group. In Powershell, when I execute `whoami /groups` I am getting back Administrators. But in C# I am not getting it. Also I do not see a proper one to one mapping  between them. IF I try `User.IsInRole("BUILTIN\\Administrators")` it returns false. What am I doing wrong here?

Side by side Results:
[image: Side by side Results]

Code:
[image: Code]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IsInRole always returns "User" for account type "Administrator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939008/isinrole-always-returns-user-for-account-type-administrator)

Comment: Thanks Martheen, This one partially helped me, I could use the code on page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.isinrole?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Security_Principal_WindowsPrincipal_IsInRole_System_Security_Principal_WindowsBuiltInRole_

Comment: As per the above suggestion, I tried the code on page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.isinrole?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Security_Principal_WindowsPrincipal_IsInRole_System_Security_Principal_WindowsBuiltInRole_ which is getting the result in windows console app, but not in a web api. Is this possible at all in web api? If not why?

Comment: Er, web api? You don't want to run your API service as admin, and even if you use Windows authentication for your API users, you usually don't want/need them to use it as admin either.

Comment: Thanks Martheen. This is not a production grade API. I was just trying some code randomly and was trying to use the local windows groups with Windows Authentication/Authorization samples